# Unable to convert tensorflow Mask-Rcnn to IR with Open Vino toolkit

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, faster-rcnn, openvino

```
python mo_tf.py 
--saved_model_dir C:\DATASETS\mask50000\exports\saved_model 
--output_dir C:\DATASETS\mask50000 
--reverse_input_channels 
--tensorflow_custom_operations_config extensions\front\tf\mask_rcnn_support_api_v2.0.json
--tensorflow_object_detection_api_pipeline_config C:\DATASETS\mask50000\exports\pipeline.config 
--log_level=DEBUG
```

I have been trying to convert the model using the above script, but every time I got the error:

"Exception: Exception occurred during running replacer "REPLACEMENT_ID (<class'extensions.front.tf.tensorflow_custom_operations_config_update.TensorflowCustomOperationsConfigUpdate'>)": The function 'update_custom_layer_attributes' must be implemented in the      sub-class."

I have exported the graph using exporter_main_v2.py. If more information is needed please inform me.

EDIT:
I was able to convert the model by changing the file  mask_rcnn_support_api_v2.4.json.

first change:
"custom_attributes": {
"operation_to_add": "Proposal",
"clip_before_nms": false,
"clip_after_nms": true
}
second change:
"start_points": [
"StatefulPartitionedCall/concat/concat",
"StatefulPartitionedCall/concat_1/concat",
"StatefulPartitionedCall/GridAnchorGenerator/Identity",
"StatefulPartitionedCall/Cast",
"StatefulPartitionedCall/Cast_1",
"StatefulPartitionedCall/Shape"
]

that solved the problme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenVINO 2020.4 is not compatible with TensorFlow 2. Support for TF 2.0 Object Detection API models was fully enabled only in OpenVINO 2021.3.

I’ve successfully converted the model [mask_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_1024x1024_coco17](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20200711/mask_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_1024x1024_coco17_gpu-8.tar.gz) to IR using the latest OpenVINO release (2021.4.752).

I share the MO conversion command here:

*python mo_tf.py --saved_model_dir <model_dir>\saved_model --tensorflow_object_detection_api_pipeline_config <pipeline_dir>\pipeline.config --transformations_config <installed_dir>\extensions\front\tf\mask_rcnn_support_api_v2.0.json"*

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm using OpenVINO release (2021.4.752). and still get an error,  Exception occurred during running replacer "ObjectDetectionAPIPreprocessor2Replacement (<class 'extensions.front.tf.ObjectDetectionAPI.ObjectDetectionAPIPreprocessor2Replacement'>)

assert len(start_nodes) >= 1
AssertionError

Comment: Share with us your custom model for replication purposes. You can save your model in cloud storage and provide us with the link here.